# Gensim Word2Vec Training Data

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am currently trying to train my own word2vec model with my own training data and I am utterly confused about the training data preprocessing.

I ran a short script over my text which lemmatizes and also lower-cases the words in the text such that in the end my training data from a sentence (in German) like:

`"Er hat heute zwei Birnen gegessen."`

the following comes out:

`[er, haben, heute, zwei, birne, essen]`

translated in English:

`He ate two pears today.`

results in:

`[he, eat, two, pear, today]`

Now the problem is: I haven't seen anyone do this to their training data. The words are kept in uppercase and also not lemmatized and I absolutely don't get how this works. Especially for German there are so many inflections of verbs. Should I just leave them that way? I don't understand how it works not doing the lemmatization since gensim doesn't even know which language it is trained on right?

So in short: Should I do lemmatization and/or lowercasing or just leave every word as it is?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you are going to use the embeddings for, however, they are usually trained on word forms. Word embeddings are typically pre-trained on very large datasets and cover vocabularies up to 500k words, which typically covers most words in most forms even in language with much richer morphology than German.

You might also want to use [FastText](https://fasttext.cc) ([bindings for Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_fasttext.html) exist) instead of Word2Vec. FastText considers character n-gram statistics for the embeddings, so it better generalize for regularities in morphology.

But in general, the data preprocessing always depends on how do you plan to use the embeddings. If you want to do a quantitative diachronic study on how the meaning of the words shifted over the 20th century, then embedding lemmas is a good idea. If you work with low resource language that has a good lemmatizer, it also might be a good idea. If you plan to the embeddings as an input for a downstream NLP model, then you should probably use forms and/or use already pre-trained embeddings.